# How to use textboxes on a specific location inside an image

Tags: c#, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Blazor-webassembly (PWA).

I have an image where the user needs to fill in form textboxes on specific places in the image.

I've thought about using SVG images to try to insert the textboxes inside of it. But since these are generated from a png, the path's aren't great and I can't put them on the exact locations inside the image.

Does anyone know another method to insert textboxes inside an image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont think your problem has anything to do with blazor. Read about how to use z-index in HTML.